# extra spaces and newline PHP automatically get removed TEXTAREA

Tags: php, html, textarea

My code for the input php file is the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="input" action="welcome.php" method="post">
      Comment: <textarea name="input" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

For the output code it is the following.

```
<html>
  <body>
    Welcome <?php $a=$_POST["input"]; echo $a; ?><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

When anything with extra spaces and newline are inputted, it automatically gets removed. For example :

When I input:

```
abcd
cda xyzb
```

Output is:

`Welcome abcd cda xyzb`

Comment: Extra space and newline are not removed, they are just not displayed in the browser. As is the rule in HTML.

Comment: You want go to the next line like your input?

Comment: If the site is going online, read about XSS. If I type `<script>alert('hello');</script>` to the textarea. I could run javascript code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because new line characters are represented as  `\r\n`, in the sourcecode you'll see new lines. Whitespaces get truncated if one follows another in HTML.

I suggest you to use the `<pre>` tag, which does **not only save the new lines** (like php's `nl2br()`) but also preserves the **whitespaces**.

Don't forget to strip characters that would allow code injection when printing input from unknown source.

### Using `<pre>`:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre class="yourStyleForThisPreFormattedText">
Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_POST["input"]); ?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

### Using special chars (`&nbsp;`) and PHP functions:

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php $a = nl2br(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', htmlentities($_POST["input"])), true); 
echo $a; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice:

For HTML4 and HTML5 use `nl2br($str, true);`, for XHTML4 use `nl2br($str);` - the difference is in the output: `<br>` and `<br />`. See http://php.net/nl2br

Answer (score 1):

To display newline use `nl2br()`

```
<html>
    <body>
        Welcome <?php $a = nl2br($_POST["input"]); 
        echo $a; ?><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also add `<pre>` tag to show preformatted text (all whitespaces).

Comment: How to add extra spaces? For example two spaces or so.

Comment: @AnandSinghKunwar Using `<pre>` in html or `str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $string);` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<textarea name="input" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Into

```
<textarea name="input" rows="5" cols="40" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

You can also use wrap: off, hard, soft, physical

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_POST['input']); ?>
```

`htmlentities()` converts your HTML.