# Script for Code tag from php/html/css

Tags: php, html, css

I wrote some code from my project to textarea and save it to my database.
after i wanted read and write from database to some panel on web and the code did not have the spacing and line spacing

example:

i write to textare this

```
function write($text) {
    echo"$text";
}
```

and this code looks like this panel

```
function write($text) {
echo"$text";
}
```

please thank you for replies
and sorry for my english :D thanks

Comment: So you want your code to be indented?

Comment: Do you mean the whitespace chars are not stored in the database, or not displayed properly?

Comment: @mus I think that is what the issue. He is inputting `code` into a HTML text area and the indentation isn't transferring over.

Comment: Are you displaying the code in a textarea, or as text on a page? In the latter case, you need to put the code in a `<pre>` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [extra spaces and newline PHP automatically get removed TEXTAREA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313307/extra-spaces-and-newline-php-automatically-get-removed-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your text area with `<pre>` tags as found in this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313432/2677083

Sample code from [@DanFromGermany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948292/danfromgermany):

**Using `<pre>`:**

```
<html>
<body>
<pre class="yourStyleForThisPreFormattedText">
Welcome <?php $a = $_POST["input"]; 
echo $a; ?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation from [@DanFromGermany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948292/danfromgermany):

> This is because new line characters are represented as  \r\n, in the
>   sourcecode you'll see new lines. Whitespaces get truncated if one
>   follows another in HTML.
>
> I suggest you to use the  tag, which does not only save the new
>   lines (like php's nl2br()) but also preserves the whitespaces.
>
> Notice:
>
> For HTML4 and HTML5 use nl2br($str, true);, for XHTML4 use
>   nl2br($str); - the difference is in the output: `<br> and <br />`. See http://php.net/nl2br